# href in HTML and forward slash (/) and %2F?

Tags: java, html

I am generating an HTML page that lists files in a directory in Java. Each file name is placed in a link to the file. Since the directory names and file names contain non-ASCII characters and spaces, I used the following method to encode them.

```
URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
```

I can either put the full directory to `href` of `<base>` or append it to the `href` of `<a>` for each file. That method above converts `/` to `%2F`. But I have seen `href` contains `/`.

So,

1. should I replace `/` to `%2F` or
2. should I leave `/` as it is or
3. it does not matter whether it is `/` or `%2F`?

If the answer is 2, what Java method should I use instead of URLEncoder.encode() because it replaces `/` with `%2F`.

Comment: it depends if the `/` is acting as a path separator, or as part of the query.

Comment: It is part of the file path. For example, if the requested page is "http:///mysite/a/b/c", and the "a/b/c" directory contains c1.txt, c2.txt..., either the base can be "/a/b/c" and file link can be "c1.txt" or there is no base and the file link can be "/a/b/c/c1.txt".

Comment: then you should not encode it.